# Graphing a function

Tags: numerical-methods, graphing-functions, problem-solving, mathematica

A function is defined in a [article equation 37,](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.5922)
$$A(t)= 0.456+\frac{2.58}{(1+0.136 t)^{0.249}}$$
The simulation of the equation is:
[image]
But I have tried like by this:

```
Plot[.456 + (2.58/(1 + (.136) t)^(.249)), {t, 0, 7000}]
```

And the output I got:

[image]

Is there anything more arguments need to be included?

Comment: Please read the paper more carefully, it says $A(t)$ is approximately the ***amplitude***, not the oscillating simulation itself.

Comment: yup, and we need to evaluate the decay rate, I mean amplitude over the time. The author said that The Fig is based on the equation I wrote, so how did he got the fig like this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct plot by google:

[plot](https://www.google.com/search?q=.456%20%2b%20%282.58/%281%20%2b%20%28.136%29%20t%29%5E%28.249%29%29)

which is somewhat similar to the simulation.